# creating a window in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, window

I have some experience with c++, and other languages but I've only made games before using c++ and I need to make a OBS plugin.. I was wondering if anyone could help..

I'm trying to create a window with -

```
    int nHeight = 500;
int nWidth = 500;

#define metaData(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
    CreateWindowExA(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F5))
    {
        //MsgeBox::myMessage::createMessage(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Hello", (LPCWSTR)L"I See You.", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
        #define CreateWindow metaData;
    }
```

It doesn't create a window, and it doesn't give an error.. when I call the messagebox it only appears once I try to close the window.. why is that?

How could I create a seperate window?

the tutorial im following is - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Comment: That function declaration doesn't occur anywhere in the walkthrough you're following. Consider following it more closely. If you don't know the difference between a function declaration and a function call, it's probably time to revisit your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @molbdnilo I had a derp-moment, sorry ^^ let me update my question

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of trouble simply by following the tutorial that you say you're following. (Those macros make no sense, so my book-revisitation advice still stands.)

Comment: @Molbdnilo do you have a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a message procedure then respond to key messages. For example

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wp == VK_F5)
        CreateWindow(L"ChildClass", L"Child window", 
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION, 
                    0, 0, 300, 200, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Note that you have to register a second class name for "ChildClass" and then create a different message procedure for this child class.

Then you add a separate function called `ChildProc` which is similar to `WndProc`. For example:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

HINSTANCE g_hinstance = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        if (wp == VK_F5)
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"VK_F5 detected", 0, 0);
            if (!CreateWindow(L"ChildClass", L"ChildTitle",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION, 100, 100, 300, 200,
                hwnd, 0, g_hinstance, 0))
            {
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                wchar_t buf[100];
                wsprintf(buf, L"%d\n", err);
                MessageBox(0, buf, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    wcex.lpszClassName = L"ChildClass";
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    CreateWindow(L"MainClass", L"MainTitle", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: When I try to implement this it expects a ; after the first {

Comment: I don't understand the error message. After which `{`?

Comment: after - LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{

it also says - Error 1 error C2601: 'WndProc' : local function definitions are illegal c:\path

Comment: What compiler are you using? Don't mix Unicode and ANSI functions. See updated answer. By the way, you changed your question and now your new code is mixing ANSI and Unicode functions. `CreateWindowA` is ANSI (which is old). If UNICODE is defined for a new projects, then just use `CreateWindow` which should be a macro for `CreateWindowW` and it takes wide string characters (for example L"Title")

Comment: that fixed the compiler issue, but no new window is being generated

Comment: Look at the note for **`GetLastError`**. Update your question and tell us what is the result for `GetLastError`. Also make sure you have the right `hinstance` if this is in a plugin.